# How to find the number of permutations in which Amit is at the left end of the line or Ed is at the right end of the line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Amit, Brian, Connor, Dan and Ed stand in a line. Find the number of possible permutations in which
(a) Amit is at one end of the line
(b) Amit is not at either end
(c) Amit is at the left end of the line or Ed is at the right end, or both

I am stuck on part c of this question.

So far, I've gotten $4!+4!+(4! \cdot 4!)$

$4!$ being the ways which the possible arrangements of which Amit and Ed are at the ends of the lines, but this is wrong.

Comment: Well, in working $(c)$, note that the two events are not mutually exclusive.  Thus you can't just add the two cases, you have to subtract off the cases in which both occur.

Comment: The number of permutations in which Amit is at the left end of the line is $4!$; the number of permutations in which Ed is at the right end of the line is $4!$.  How many permutations are there in which Amit is at the left end of the line and Ed is at the right end of the line?

Comment: If Amit is at the left end of the line and Ed is at the right end of the line, then the $(4! + 4!)$ computation has counted that specific situation $\color{red}{\text{twice}}.$

Comment: See the Inclusion–exclusion principle, for example [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for a method of avoiding double counting mentioned in another comment.